# Friends and namespaces

Tags: c++

I have been experimenting with friends and have come across something that I cannot explain

If I declare a class as

```
 class MyClass: public QObject
 {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  friend int main(int,char**);

 private:
  MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

 };
```

Then I can instantiate a MyClass in main –

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MyClass*  = new MyClass;
 raiigui w;
 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

However, if I place MyClass inside a namespace –

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
 class MyClass: public QObject
 {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  friend int main(int,char**);

 private:
  MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);  
 };
}
```

I cannot now instantiate MyClass

```
MyNamespace::MyClass mc = new MyNamespace::MyClass;
```

Could anybody explain why this is?

Thanks

Comment: The missing `*` in `MyNamespace::MyClass mc = new MyNamespace::MyClass;`?

Comment: Yep and the constructor call as well. Should be `MyNamespace::MyClass* mc = new MyNamespace::MyClass();`

Comment: Even with the missing * I get a compilation error that says main cannot access MyClass

Comment: @Vinzenz: *"and the constructor call as well"* - you don't need parenthesis to call the constructor... see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Comment: @TonyD you are right. Sorry I thought this was only possible with Objects on the Heap and Stack :/

Answer (score 2):

`friend int main(int,char**);` declares `main` in `namespace MyNamespace`. To declare a friend function from another namespace you have to fully specify the namespace, and that in turn requires `main` to be forward-declared:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass: public QObject
    {
        friend int ::main(int,char**);
        //         ^^^^^^
    private:
        MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);  
    };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     MyNamespace::MyClass* mc = new MyNamespace::MyClass;
}
```